# <f:loadBundle basename

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

i have a jsp file Trainer.jsp in which there's a code

```
$<f:loadBundle basename="kk.saken.jsf.starter.messages" var="msg" />
```

the problem is 'Resource bundle jsf.starter.messages cannot be found on classpath'

when i run the Trainer.jsp it shows:

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name kk.saken.jsf.starter.messages, locale en_US
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:413)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:364)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)


root cause 

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name kk.saken.jsf.starter.messages, locale en_US
    java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
    java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
    java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1028)
    com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.LoadBundleTag.doStartTag(LoadBundleTag.java:164)
    org.apache.jsp.Trainer_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005floadBundle_005f0(Trainer_jsp.java:179)
    org.apache.jsp.Trainer_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(Trainer_jsp.java:135)
    org.apache.jsp.Trainer_jsp._jspService(Trainer_jsp.java:98)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:364)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final logs.

Answer (score 0):

rename `kk.saken.jsf.starter.messages` to `kk.saken.jsf.starter.messages_en_US` and Try access the page.

Comment: thanks screemanth, that's settled now everything looks good with the exception that in the project folder there's this little red -x sign have appeared, and when i run the project this is showing up:


`HTTP Status 404 - `

`--------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

`type Status report`

`message

description`

`The requested resource () is not available.`


`GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2`

but actually i'm running my project on jboss app server 7.1 in
eclipse jee juno